# Cannot retrieve public posts via Facebook Graph Explorer due to "Unsupported GET request"

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve a number of public posts from facebook via the Graph Explorer Interface, and I'm running into the "Unsupported get request" exception.

A lot of posts on StackOverflow say that this is because you need to acquire some user_access permission, but as far as I understand, that shouldn't be the case here.

The ID of one of the posts I'm trying to access is:

```
224393774239629_508106655868338
```

If it were restricted, I shouldn't be able to see post here without logging into facebook:

[http://www.facebook.com/224393774239629/posts/508106655868338](http://www.facebook.com/224393774239629/posts/480858081926529)

So that should rule out the problem with restriced access.

So is this a bug in the facebook graph explorer?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, weird.

The link to facebook I put in *does* actually require you to login to facebook. But if you copy-paste the link into the addressbar instead, you apparently bypass that restriction, which led me to believe that the link didn't require login.

So I suppose I'm back to figring out the access restriction issue.